# Index information in git

Tags: git, github

Please, what is information given by `index` in this context:

```
diff --git a/gitk-git/gitk b/gitk-git/gitk
index 2a92e20..29b18d9 100755
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's the hash of the file `gitk-git/gitk` contents without/before and with/after the patch (diff).